# Do case statements inside a for loop work in verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

I am doing a code for radix-4 booth encoding for 8*8 multiplication. The logic is correct and there are no errors or warning. The output am getting is totally unrelated. i have posted the code below

```
module comp8mul (a, b, outc, clk);
  input [7:0] a, b;
  input clk;
  output [4:0] outc;
  wire [8:0] a1;
  reg [8:0] a12;
  wire [11:0] b1;
  integer i;
  reg [2:0] c1;
  reg [11:0] ou1;
  reg [4:0] b11 [0:11];
  reg [4:0] s1;

  assign a1 = {1'b0,a};
  assign b1 = {1'b0,b,1'b0,1'b0};
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    for (i=11; i>=2'd2; i=i-(2'd2)) begin:rloop
      c1={b1[i-2'd2],b1[i-1'b1],b1[i]};

      case(c1)
      3'b000: begin
        ou1=11'b0;
        s1[(i-(2'd3))/2'd2]=1'b0;
      end
      3'b001: begin
        ou1=a1;
        s1[(i-(2'd3))/2'd2]=1'b0;
      end
      3'b010: begin
        ou1=a1;
        s1[(i-2'd3)/2'd2]=1'b0;
      end
      3'b011: begin
        a12=a1<<1;
        ou1=(~a12)+1'b1;
        s1[(i-(2'd3))/2'd2]=1'b1;
      end
      3'b100: begin
        a12=a1<<1'b1;
        ou1=(~a12)+1'b1;
        s1[(i-(2'd3))/2'd2]=1'b1;
      end
      3'b101: begin
        ou1=(~a1);
        s1[(i-(2'd3))/2'd2]=1'b1;
      end
      3'b110: begin
        ou1=(~a1);
        s1[(i-(2'd3))/2'd2]=1'b1;
      end
      3'b111: begin
        ou1=12'b0;
        s1[(i-(2'd3))/2'd2]=1'b0;
      end
      endcase
      if (((i-(2'd3))/2'd2)==3'd4) begin
        b11[((i-(2'd3))/(2'd2))]={(~s1[(i-(2'd3))/(2'd2)]),s1[(i-(2'd3))/(2'd2)],s1[(i-(2'd3))/2'd2],ou1};

      end
      if (((i-(2'd3))/(2'd2))==1'b1) begin
        b11[(i-(2'd3))/(2'd2)]={(~s1[(i-(2'd3))/(2'd2)]),ou1};
      end
      if(((i-(2'd3))/(2'd2))==1'b0) begin
        b11[((i-(2'd3))/(2'd2))]=ou1;
      end else
        b11[(i-(2'd3))/(2'd2)]={1'b1,(~s1[(i-(2'd3))/(2'd2)]),ou1};
    end
  end
  assign outc = b11[0];
endmodule
```

I should get five 12-bit partial products as outputs. I am assigning 1 row of the 2-d array to output and checking it.

Comment: @twinkle: I can not figure out what you are asking.  What is the output you are getting that seems unexpected to you?

Comment: Show your testbench - what goes in, what comes out. What did you expect to get out?

Comment: Yes, you can use a case statement inside a for loop. However you do realize that the entire for loop will execute instantaneously (all 12 loops on the first posedge clock), right?

Answer (score 1):

If "five 12-bit partial products as outputs" desired, then `reg [4:0] b11 [0:11];` should be `reg [11:0] b11 [0:4];`.

Your b11 calculation is likely incorrect. There are missing `else`s before many of the `if` statements. Therefore, all except the final `if` condition with fall into the final `else` condition. You need to nest the else-ifs. Alternatively ,you can use another case statement. Also you need to control the `ou1` range otherwise the upper assigned bits will be out of range for `b11` and masked out.

Suggestion: `(i-2'd3)/2'd2` and format variations of the same equations is used many places. Assign it to a variable, such as `reg [2:0] c2`, and call the variable (`c2`) instead of the equation. `c2` should be assigned just like your `c1`. This will help readability of the code and lower chances of a typo.